# Attendee not getting meeting invite on creating event using service account, google calendar API

Tags: google-api, calendar, service-accounts, google-calendar-api

Hi I am creating an event using service account and added attendees. The response returned correctly but attendees are not getting invite mails. The Service account is not linked (shared) with any google account. Though to login into API console I used my gmail account. Calendar Id was given as Primary. Where the event will get created, on Service account's Calendar or my primary Calendar?. I could not see it on mine Calendar but response returned with Status "Confirmed". I am more interested in invites rather where the original event got created.

Any help would be appreciated !!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that a service account is not you.   Think of a service account as a dummy user.  It has its own calendar account, drive account and probably a bunch more.    When you inserted an event into primary you inserted it into the service accounts primary calendar.

You have a few options.

1. Share your primary calendar with the service account. Just add it as a user.  Find the calendar id in the settings and have the service  account insert into that calendar id.
2. Have the service account share its primary calendar with you by granting you permissions to it.  you should then be able to see it on the bottom left hand side of the Google calendar website.
3. Have the service account invite you to the event on the service accounts Google calendar.
4. Have the service account create the event with you as an attendee [event.insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) check the body of the request.

Comment: Have user A share the calendar with the Service accounts email address.  This is option number one.   You cant write to someones calendar without their permission.  You must either use Oauth2 to authenticate the user (showing the consent screen) or preauthorize the service account by sharing the calendar with the service account.

Comment: I have an article on how service accounts work it may help you understand your options better http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-service-account/

Comment: Thanks for info but our requirement is bit different, Our application creates events between 2 users (say A and B on any domain) on another platform and we want to Sync users google Calendar with that event created. So we thought of sending invite to an user A and B, (Ideally A should be the organizer but we don't want A to show the user consent screen so we though of creating a service account. We want to create same event on service accounts calendar and send invites to a A and B so they can attach it to their Calendar by accepting it. (organizer is not important)

Comment: Check option four.   Have the service account create the event with user A and B as attendees . remember to include reminders and sendNotifications in the body.   The service account will own the event and appear as the organizer.  There is no way around this, remember just because you want to do something does not mean that the API will support it.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what we want, I have added sendNotifications = true in request header parameter and not in body (as mentioned in other forums) (Do I need to add reminders as well?). In response we get Status as confirmed, along with event-id and attendee info but the attendees do not get invite mail.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/sharing#inviting_attendees_to_events

Comment: I have gone through this link but am I missing anything, It doesn't says anything specific except that one way to share event is to add attendees, that is what we are trying to achieve, I hope we don't need to share Calendars in our scenario

Comment: You don't need to share the calendar just add the attendees.